# Defining a set using a predicate

Tags: logic

I encountered this notation in a proof and I'm a bit confused on the message it's trying to convey:

> $ B = \{ n \in \mathbb N \mid \neg P(n) \} $

Here's the notation itself within the greater context of the proof (or proof 'fragment' more like):

...

$ P(n): $ predicate-definition

Assume $ \exists n \in \mathbb N, \neg P(n) $

Then $ B = \{ n \in \mathbb N \mid \neg P(n) \} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; $ #Since $ B $ is non empty and a subset of $ \mathbb N $ it must have a least element

Then $ \forall b \in B, \Rightarrow \neg P(b) $

Then $ \exists c \in B, \forall d \in B, c \leq d, \Rightarrow c - 1 \notin B \Rightarrow P(c - 1) $

...

My question is, what exactly is $ B $ ? Is it the set of all the natural numbers that make $ P(n) $ false?

Comment: That is exactly right. The notation $X = \{x\ |\ y\}$ means that $X$ is the set of all $x$ such that condition (or conditions) $y$ are satisfied. $x$ and $y$ can be more complex statements, as is the case in your example

Comment: @KeeranBrabazon, you should consider making your comment an answer.

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly right. The notation $X=\{x\ |\ y\}$ means that $X$ is the set of all $x$ such that condition (or conditions) $y$ are satisfied. $x$ and $y$ can be more complex statements, as is the case in your example